# How to turn the ouputs of a table into a value? R

Tags: r

I have the following table

```
> table(iris$Species)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        50         50         50
```

My goal is programmatically get the values of each species stored in a value
I have been doing this, but if my table changes then I will have to manually update it.

```
Set_Num <- 50
Ver_Num <- 50
Vir_Num <- 50
```

Is there a way I can do this programmatically?

Comment: It would be much easier just to leave them in the table, which is really just a named vector. If you have `tt <- table(iris$Species)`. Then you can get values out with `tt["setosa"]` or `tt["versicolor"]`. Not sure why separate variables would be better.

Comment: *"but if my table changes then I will have to manually update it"*... if you automate the creation of those variables, you will still have to update any subsequent uses of them whenever your data updates. This is super fragile. Listen to MrFlick's advice. Keep them in a `table`, put them in a `data.frame`, a `list`, whatever, but don't clutter your environment with programmatically named objects.

Comment: I'm with MrFlick and GregorThomas: despite the three answers below that show you some ways that you can do it, I think it's a bad idea to try to track statistics in this fashion. `tt["setosa"]` is far better programmatically, unambiguous, and traceable. Code-maintenance should be a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

We can use  `list2env` on a named `list` if the objective is to create multiple objects in the global env (not recommended though)

```
lst1 <- as.list(table(iris$Species))
names(lst1) <- paste0(sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", substr(names(lst1), 1, 3),
         perl = TRUE), "_Num")
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
Set_Num
#[1] 50

Ver_Num
#[1] 50

Vir_Num
#[1] 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I second all the comments made above about not flooding your global environment. However, you *could* do sth. like

```
for (i in 1:length(table(iris$Species)))
{
  assign(paste0("x", i), table(iris$Species)[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
df <- table(iris$Species)

names <- c('Set_Num',
           'Ver_Num',
           'Vir_Num' )

for (i in 1:length(df)) {
  assign(names[i], df[i])
  
}
```